# Open Default File Manager in android?

Tags: android, file-manager

My Android Device contains Default File Manager and a Button (Open). How to open the file manager when I click the button?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try something like this in your button listener:

```
openButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
      Intent intent = new Intent();
      intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
      intent.setType("file/*");
      startActivity(intent);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It's working for me. But When I select a Button List Out `File Manager` and `OfficeSuite`. How do avoid `OfficeSuite` and then select a Button to View Only `Default File Manager`. Give me any idea..

Comment: I'm not sure that is possible or even recommended. A user may not have a default file browser, so I think the best approach is to let the user choose what application he wants to browse files with. Anyway I'll search a bit and let you know if there is other way to do it.

Comment: This also showing google drive and extra folders. I want to hide or exclude google drive option . How to achieve it ?

Comment: The following code will hide Google Drive: `intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);`

Comment: Excellent... However, it is showing me the google drive and extra folders as written in above comments.. But, they arent accessible. How can I access them

Comment: For me this is opening the Wikipedia app.