# How to open file manager and select specific file type in my app?

Tags: android, android-intent, filepath, file-manager

I use the following code in my Android app to open the gallery and select a video file.

Now I want to modify this code to open the file manager, and select a file of specific type ( for example *.xyz). How can I do this !?

```
public View.OnClickListener btnChoosePhotoPressed = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent_file = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Video.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            final int ACTIVITY_SELECT_IMAGE = 1234;
            startActivityForResult(intent_file, ACTIVITY_SELECT_IMAGE);
        }
    };


protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);    
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 1234:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {        

                    Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                    String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA};

                    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);                        
                    cursor.moveToFirst();
                    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);                        
                    final String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                    cursor.close();

                    // Now I use filePath to access the file.

                }
        }
};
```

I searched for similar questions and this answer was helpful: [Open Default File Manager in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11720032/open-default-file-manager-in-android)
It helps to open the file manager. However, how can I handle the second part of my code about `cursor`, `filePathColumn`, and `filepath` !? I need the `filePath` to access the file.

Any help is highly appreciated.

---

***EDIT 1 :***

I changed my code to the following:

```
public View.OnClickListener btnChoosePhotoPressed = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent_file = new Intent();
            final int ACTIVITY_SELECT_IMAGE = 1234;
            intent_file.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent_file.setType("video/*");
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent_file, "Select Picture"),ACTIVITY_SELECT_IMAGE);
        }
    };


protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);    
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 1234:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {        

                    Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                    final String filePath = selectedImage.getPath();

                }
        }
};
```

This time, it opens the file manager to select the file. But unfortunately, the `filePath` is somehow incorrect. Because later in my code, I use the following methods to send the file via sftp, which fails, and no file is transferred.

```
File file = new File(filePath);
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
channelSftp2.put(fis, file.getName());
fis.close();
```

So, any suggestions?

Comment: This link will help you to solve your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169649/get-pick-an-image-from-androids-built-in-gallery-app-programmatically

Comment: `final int ACTIVITY_SELECT_IMAGE = 1234;`. AND `case 1234:` do not make sense.

Comment: `final String filePath = selectedImage.getPath();`. You do not get a file path. You get a content scheme. Have a look at `data.getData().toString()`.